# Iphone UiNavigation controller types

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In examples I have seen of `UINavigationContoller` and `UITableView`, switching to next view is usually triggered by tapping into that cell and pushing a different `UIViewController` on top of stack, but what I want is to switch to next view by pressing a next button in bottom of page, which I want it to load the same `UITableViewController` again but with different contents in each cell.

-Can I put that next button on bottom of page? and where
-Can I call the same controller (but showing different contents) and put on top of stack using the `UINavigationController`?

Because I want to be able to browse back previos pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally do as you highlighted first and push a new `UIViewController` subclass onto the `UINavigationController`.

A `UIViewController` is supposed to manage one screens worth of content. If you plan on breaking that convention by presenting different information you are essentially going to have duplicated `if` statements to decide whether the user should be viewing the content from before or after the button was tapped.

`UINavigationController`'s are good for hierarchal data where the content becomes more specific as you drill down. The `UINavigationController` will also manage the stack so that you can go to previous pages.

To achieve what you want to achieve ([stated here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616447/iphone-create-a-custom-uiobject) you should be using a `UINavigationController` with your custom subclass of `UITableViewController` when the user submits questions you receive your xml, parse it and then instantiate a new instance of your `UITableViewController` subclass and push it onto the stack.

Comment: tnx this is detaied explaination of my problem, they suggested this approach, what u think?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616447/iphone-create-a-custom-uiobject

Comment: To give the ability to simply step back then you should probably use the `UINavigationController` and just push on a new `UITableViewController`. I am not sure I understand why you do not want to keep it in one view controller especially if there are several levels of questions (you will need to remember all of the questions at previous levels to provide the functionality to go back). Instantiate a new instance of your `UITableViewController` and push it onto the stack.

Comment: yes I will create new instance of tabeview controler and push. I will also have customized UITableViewCells, and each page will consist of a combination of those sublassed cells. so do also need controllers for each subclassed cell?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It sounds to me like you could do with having a look at some iPhone development books to get a better grounding. It will be a lot quicker than asking a question for every aspect of your application. The concept for your app sounds like it will work and you know what is required from a high level you just need the lower level implementation knowledge to back it.

Comment: please look here I asked more cleary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636101/iphone-uitableviewcell-customazitaion

Answer (score 1):

Just make your `UITableViewDatasource` returning your number of rows plus one in the last section you have in `–(NSUInteger)tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Set any content for that cell before returning it to the tableView.

Then only push a new `UIVIewController`, when the user touches that last cell.
You could also make the delegate of the `UITableView` returning `nil` on :

`-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` for the cells you don't want the user select.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button in the footer view of your table view. To achieve this have a look at `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`. Then add an action to that button which allocs and inits the view controller with the new content and pushes it onto the stack.

Comment: tnx if I use this approach can I still use uinavigationcaontroller?

Comment: Sure! Just push the new view controller onto the stack of the navigation controller.