# Iphone UITableViewCell customazitaion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a UInavigation controller, UITabelView with customized UITableViewCells, which I will create 4 different xib files for that custom cells, which I will get user input from them.

I am a bit confused here, it is said every view should have its own controller in Iphone, so I will push a new subclass of UItableviewcontroller on stack for each page(UITableView), and in theory it should be responsible for the delegations of the uicomponents on that table. But each UItableVIew consists of customized cells(xibs),

So 
-Do I also need a different controller for each customized cell?

-If so, where can I put the delegation methods of those ui components on the custom cells?

-is this hiearchy correct?

UINavigationController--> UITableViewControllersSubclasses  -->customUITableViewCellcontrollers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You do **not** need a different controller for each customized cell.

> it is said every view should have its
>   own controller in Iphone

This is not true. Actually, a view controller typically manages a *view hierarchy* rather than a view. Although the view controller is associated with a view, this view is just the root of the whole view hierarchy of a screen’s worth of content (in iPhone applications).

From [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457):

> Each view controller is responsible
>   for managing a discrete part of your
>   application’s user interface. View
>   controllers are directly associated
>   with a single view object but that
>   object is often just the root view of
>   a much larger view hierarchy that is
>   also managed by the view controller.
>   The view controller acts as the
>   central coordinating agent for the
>   view hierarchy, handling exchanges
>   between its views and any relevant
>   controller or data objects. A single
>   view controller typically manages the
>   views associated with a single
>   screen’s worth of content, although in
>   iPad applications this may not always
>   be the case.

Comment: So if every custom cell have their own different user input uicomponents, their delegations should be handled all in the instance of the UITableviewcontrollersubclass? the uitableview will be dynamically filled with these custom cells which they include textboxes, switchs, pickers..etc. one page can include all types of cells or only one type of cell, depending on what it receives from web service..can I handle this with one controller?

Comment: @XDeveloper Yes, you use a single view controller to manage a screen's worth of content. If you want to manage different regions of your screen with different objects, use custom objects descending from `NSObject` instead of view controllers and then manage *those* with a single view controller.

Comment: @XDeveloper Extending my previous comment, let me quote the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12) again: "If you want to divide a view hierarchy into multiple subareas and manage each one separately, use generic controller objects (custom objects descending from NSObject) instead of view controller objects to manage each subarea. Then use a single view controller object to manage the generic controller objects."

Comment: tnx I understand but then where should I put the releted delegate methods, in classes descending from NSObject or all in uitableview controller?

Comment: @XDeveloper I would start with a single view controller. If, at some point, you feel this controller has grown too much or does too many things then you divide up into multiple generic controller objects.

Comment: and I couldnt find a document telling how to implement a generic controller

Comment: @albertamg let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1290/discussion-between-xdeveloper-and-albertamg)

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you are trying to build a question form. Your design could look like this.

Your Page will be UITableViewController that contains lets say two different type of cells. Cell A and cell B. B/c you want to have different behavior and design of those two cells you want to subclass UITableCellView for both cell A and cell B. In those subclases you will handle how the cell behaves. Your UITableViewController on the other hand will manage all the cells together.

So this is how to do it.

**Step One**

First let's create a custom cell A (subclass of UITableViewCell)

//CustomCellA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCellA : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel *name;
    NSArray *dataSource
    int value;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *dataSource;
@property(nonatomic,readwrite)int value;

@end
```

//CustomCellA.m

```
#import "CustomCellA.h"

@implementation CustomCellA

@synthesize name;
@synthesize dataSource;
@synthesize type;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        name       = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        datasource = [NSArray alloc] init];
        value      = -1;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [dataSource release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Edit the content of CustomCellA.xib file.

- Change cells class to CustomCellA.
- Give a cell Identifier "CustomCellA"

**Step Two**

Desing cell B just like cell A above

**Step Three**

Now in your UITableViewController you can use your cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    //Use your dataSource example an NSArray field with questions as NSDictionary:
    NSDictionary*question = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int questionType = [question integerForKey:@"type"];

    if(questionType == 0){//cell A

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellA";
       static NSString *CellNib = @"CustomCellA";

       UserCustomTableCell *cell = (CustomCellA *)[table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil) {
           NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
           cell = (CustomCellA *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
       }

       // setup your cell

    }else{
        //Do the same for cell B
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, this was very very helpful. If I want to use a picker view in one of the cells, I guess thats not good because they both use gestures, so can I make it pop up the in same screen somehow?

Comment: Yes you can make it pop'up, use UIAlertSheet. You can trigger the UIAlertSheet in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath: in your UITableViewController by checking cells type.

Comment: could you also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637140/iphone-uitableviewcell-with-checkbox