# iPhone UITableViewCell with checkbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a custom-subclassed `UITableViewCell` which will include a few labels, to which I want to add some checkbox functionality. One question label and five options are multi-selectable in that `UITableviewCell` subclass

Since I'm already in a cell, is it possible to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` to imitate checkbox functionality? Another option would be to navigate to another tableview using `UINavigationController`, but I want the user to see the options in the same page.

Also, since I don't know the number of options beforehand, is it possible to design this custom cell using a XIB and yet still dynamically add some items (for example `UISwitch`, or `UIButton`s) at runtime? Or do I have to code it all without using a XIB?

Comment: have you considered adding uiimages that change state based on when/where it was clicked?   

you could place an invisible button over each of your check fields and tag it based on the row (and column), so that when it is clicked, you can add a check mark image over the blank box.

Comment: @calvinBhai tnx can I create this cell using xib and still add rows on runtime? or I must code the subclass of tablecell withour xib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, Yes.

`UITableViewCell` is a subclass (somewhere down the way) of a `UIView`. That said you can insert a `UITableView` in it and create your checkbox allike cells. Think of it as nested tables:

`Table of questions -> question cell -> table of answers -> answer cell`.

So what you want to do is to make your custom `UITableViewCell` implement `UITableViewDelegate` and  `UITableViewDataSource` then you want to insert an UITableView in the IB.

When you want to show your question cell with 4 answers you would pass a parameter of answers as a `NSArray` to the custom `UITableViewCell`. It then will use it to create inner cells that will behave as answer cells.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, making my custom UITableViewCell means I will subclass it or customize it? And the number of options will be avaliable on runtime is that a propblem? and also I want the label fonts, label place..etc kind of things to be dynamic, so still can I design it in xib and overwrite dynamically in code ?

Comment: You will subclass it and customize it then. As for the other question: Yes you can do all that at runtime. You can override the init method of you custom cell to adjust itself on creation.

Comment: and finally do you recommened doing this from apples perspective, or should carry my uitable to another uiview. I read somewhere it is not standart way of doing things

Comment: this is my new idea,using NavigationController I will create different UIViews with xibs, lets say 5 xib. UITable rows will only contain the question text, then when user clicks a row in the uitable I will swap views by choosing one of xibs I created the related question and options . I should do this if this will give me more flexibility bacause designing a uiview should be more easy and flexible than designing a customcell. correct?

Comment: but then I need to have 5 uicontrolelrs and a navigation controller for all those uiviews, is that normal or easy to handle too much view controllers?

Comment: You could do it as you described it above, but looking from the perspective of you users, it would be much better for them to see a page(UITableView) with questions and answers. It will let them answer quickly. With your design there will be too much animations and switching. Btw designing UITableCellView is as easy as designing UIView.

Comment: tnx do I need a tableview controller to control that inner uitable? if not where do i implement its delegation methods

Comment: You implement it's delegate methods inside the UITableCellView subclass. Thats the class that represets question.